# Problems to build app for 10.5 with xcode 3.2.3

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

I was trying to compile my project under xcode 3.2.3 to make it run on OS X 10.5 
I've set the SDKROOT to macosx10.5 and Deployment Target to 10.5, but it still shows to use SDK  10.6 during compiling. And it changed the minimumversion to 10.6 in built Info.plist.

Anybody get any ideas on this??

Answer (score 0):

Check that your SDK setting etc is not being overridden, i.e. look at the *target* settings. Also make sure that you didn't change it just for, say, Development or Deployment builds - you probably want it set to the same for both.

Comment: Yes Paul, I set all to 10.5 for both Development and Deployment builds. But it still uses sdk 10.6 during compiling.

Comment: Did you check it at the *target* level though, not just at the *project* level ?

Comment: the problem is I set SDKROOT to 10.5 but it seems still using 10.6 during compiling, looks like -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk

Comment: Solved, for some strange reason, the basesdk was not changed, I edit the project file manually solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes Paul, I set all to 10.5 for both Development and Deployment builds. But it still uses sdk 10.6 during compiling.